# In TypeScript how can I ensure literal types read/write correspondence?

Tags: typescript

My API has functions that perform operations based on string literals:

```ts
function write< Type >( destination : string, data : Type ) { ... }
function read< Type >( source : string ) : Type { ... }
```

When API user arbitrarily calls these functions throughout his code, how can I ensure that types of all read/write operations match, so that for `destination/source` specified all used types must be exactly the same?

Should I use [object literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) to eventually [const evaluate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) it's keys? If so, how can I statically check that object literal type wasn't yet defined so it needs to be initialized instead of being checked against void for correspondence? How can I invoke const expression evaluation only after the whole code (all read()/write() calls) was compiled?

Should/can I do it in `*.d.ts` files?

Comment: Are the destinations/sources strings fixed or dynamic? E. g., the user can write on arbitrary new destinations instead of using some predefined destinations.

Comment: @MircoS. `source/destination`s are completely arbitrary - no predefined sets. I want **TypeScript** compiler to find all the `read(a)` calls and ensure that they all have corresponding `write(a)` with exactly the same type. It would be cool to obtain type inference for `read(a)` return values based on existing (which we ensure) `write(a)`s and vice versa, but I already feel like I'm asking too much ^^

Comment: Without an object that is returned from write/read calls on which subsequent calls are executed this is not possible.

Comment: @MircoS. can that object be global (making `read/write` being it's methods) or static?

Comment: No, it would always have to be a new object or a casted old object which is augmented with the new type information. The only way i would see this working is if the api users have to define their model beforehand and then make read/write calls on that definition.